# R filtering with subset, but Extra spaces and Characters in Brand Name returns an error

Tags: r

Disclaimer: Totally new to R I just learned about it this week.

I'm trying to filter a bunch of Brand names and export to CSV.  I have the codes working, but ran into a problem:

**Brands** that have a **SPACE** in between or symbols **" ! " , or "  '   "** in the Brand names.  This returns an error when I try to subset because of the characters.  Does anyone have a workaround or ideas how I can complete this?  I can't modify the CSV files one by one since it's a lot of data.

Here's my code:

```
COMBINEJune15Shenan'igans061516 <- subset(COMBINEJune15,Brand=="Shenan'igans")
```

> Error: unexpected string constant in "COMBINEJune15Shenan'igans061516 <- subset(COMBINEJune15,Brand=="Shenan'"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the apostrophe from the variable name.
`COMBINEJune15Shenan'igans061516` is not a legal identifier in R.

Change it to `COMBINEJune15Shenanigans061516`, `COMBINEJune15Shenan.igans061516`, or`COMBINEJune15Shenan_igans061516`.

Comment: THANK YOU!  This worked for me, I just removed any symbols /spaces in my names.  Now, to research how to run a script on this 200 times.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that I could help you. Then, would you mind to accept my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it sort of is a legal identifier in the sense of `\`COMBINEJune15Shenan'igans061516\` <- 3`, though no one would recommend that.

Comment: I used COMBINEJune15Shenanigans061516